# How to clear Chrome Site Data using DevTools Selenium Webdriver 4 C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4

I need to sign out using DevTools in Chrome. The only way to do it is to clear Local and session storage:
[image]

How can I do it using Selenium Webdriver 4 C#?

My current attempts do not complete this:

```
                var devTools = (IDevTools)Context.Driver;
                IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
                var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
                domains.Network.ClearBrowserCookies(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V114.Network.ClearBrowserCookiesCommandSettings());
                domains.Network.ClearBrowserCache(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V114.Network.ClearBrowserCacheCommandSettings(), CancellationToken.None);
                
                domains.Storage.ClearDataForStorageKey(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V114.Storage.ClearDataForStorageKeyCommandSettings());
                domains.Storage.ClearCookies(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V114.Storage.ClearCookiesCommandSettings());
                domains.Storage.ClearSharedStorageEntries(new ClearSharedStorageEntriesCommandSettings());
                domains.Storage.ClearTrustTokens(new ClearTrustTokensCommandSettings());
                domains.Storage.ClearDataForOrigin(new ClearDataForOriginCommandSettings());
                domains.Console.ClearMessages(new ClearMessagesCommandSettings());
```

Comment: Should be able to execute a script to do this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_clear.asp  Use the driver's execute script method.  There's also one for managing cookies... with a delete all cookies method.  Make sure in either case that the browser is currently at the correct domain.

Comment: @pcalkins it works only for page, not for all site as I understand. Anyway, executing it in console didn't actually sign me out :(

Comment: it'll depend on the site's method for persisting a session.  Some will persist the token in JS and send via custom header.  Other's may use a 3rd party login which has it's own persistence/domain... (user is remembered there... so they can be re-logged in after logout happens)  Take a look at requests and responses to get an idea how the site works.